# Word js API, office binding handler not called on delete or undo

Tags: api, office-js, cpu-word, word-contentcontrol, word-web-addins

I am trying to track changes on some ranges in a Word document.
I have successfully implemented this by wrapping the range in a `contentControl` and then using the office binding interface to add a binding and give it a handler with `Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged`. All this seems to work ok. When I change the text in the range, the handler is called. However if I delete the entire range, it is not called, neither is it called if I 'undo' or 'redo' to make a change. I can understand that if I have deleted the range I have deleted the contentControl and associated bindings, but surely the handler should be called one final time as the range is deleted? Definitely on undo/redo. Or have I missed something?

Comment: Can you get the effect you want by handling the [Word.ContentControl.onDeleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.contentcontrol?view=word-js-preview#onDeleted) event?

Comment: Thanks Rick. I'd missed the fact that I could handle the changes through a contentControl event, thought I had to use a binding. I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Rick, I've had a look at the Word.ContentControl events but I don't seem to be able to register them. I've posted another question about it here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70421577/cant-register-a-word-contentcontrol-event)