# Can't register a Word.ContentControl event

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-contentcontrol

I'm having difficulty using Word.ContentControl events. My code to register one on the current selection is:

```
 Word.run(function (context) {
    console.log("Creating cc");
    let range = context.document.getSelection();
    let cc = range.insertContentControl();

    return context.sync()
        .then(() => {
            cc.title = "Test";
            cc.onDataChanged.add(handleChange);
        })
        .then(context.sync)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("Content Control added:");
            console.log(cc.title, cc.onDataChanged);
        })
}).catch(errorHandler);
```

This successfully prints out the title and handler object, where I can see the name of my handler, but the handler never gets called. If I fetch the contentControl to check it with this code:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    console.log("Retrieving cc");
    let ccc, ncc: Word.ContentControlCollection;

    return context.sync()
        .then(() => {
            ccc = context.document.contentControls;
            ncc = ccc.getByTitle("Test");
            ncc.load(["items"]);
        })
        .then(context.sync)
        .then(() => {
            ncc.items[0].load(["title", "onDataChanged/all"]);
        })
        .then(context.sync)
        .then(() => {
            console.log(ncc.items[0].title, ncc.items[0].onDataChanged);
        })
}).catch(errorHandler);
```

The onDataChanged object shows there are no handlers registered.

Here is a gist for script lab:
https://gist.github.com/c5teele/f92111951d2d71e171ab193334e27b6c

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Chris, It would be helpful if you could provide a cloud link to a sample document with your content control. That way someone trying to assist will not have to hope they set up a document that has the same things. You could  do this by editing your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks Charles, I've done that and updated the question.